# VoiceOver accessibility focus on a series of elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiaccessibility

Say I have a dialog box like this:

[image: dialog box]

and I want to focus on title, then body and then each button one after another. I am able to focus on body using

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification, dialog.bodyLabel);
```

but is there any way to define a set of elements we want to focus instead of a single one?

**EDIT:**

I have also tried to make a list of elements I want to focus on using this syntax:

```
dialog.accessibilityElements = @[dialog.titleLable, dialog.bodyLable, etc];
```

but it just reads the first element (in this case `dialog.titleLable`) and doesn't move to the next one. Any thoughts?

Comment: set the isAccessibleElement to YES for the all individual elements in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The default value is set to `NO` for all the elements.

set the `isAccessibleElement` to `YES` for the all individual elements in the dialog

and then you can do

```
dialog.accessibilityElements = @[dialog.titleLable, dialog.bodyLable];
```

so that voice over reads title label first and body label next.